# Ember.js 2 Calls to .net API

Tags: c#, .net, ember.js

I am building a SPA ember.js app that will hit a .net API via an ajax call.

ember.js

```
getData: function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:9001/controller",
    dataType : "json",
    headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success : function(data) {
        return data;
    },
    error:function(data){
      alert('test' + data);
    }
  })
}
```

It returns an error message : SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'function () { return _emberRuntimeSystemString.fmt(this, arguments); }' is not a valid HTTP header field value.

I have been hammering away at this issue for a few hours now and I just can't seem to get around it. Also very new to ember.js.

If anyone has a better idea of whats going on...

Comment: `url: "http://localhost:9001/controller"` modify this to `url: "controller/method"` and that should work

Comment: I tried that as well as removing the header. The response was: "NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:9001/controller/method'."

Comment: you got me wrong `controller/method` means `your-controller-name/` followed by the method name which'll get you actual data `method-name`

Comment: I was using an incorrect URL and the header value was incorrectly used in my ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
the problem is in your headers. You are not giving "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" a value.
So you want something like

```
headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": 'value' }
```

Also, I don't think that particular header is used that way? I believe it's a header that the server sends.
Check this post out - [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Pav

Comment: I tried your answer and the response message is now just "error". 

The console is logging : 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9001/controller. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.'

Comment: Yep, your requested server must return 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. You need to return 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9001' header from your controller service

Comment: I removed the header. The response was: "NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'localhost:9001/controller/method'." So I think this is more of an issue with the controller

Comment: I was using an incorrect URL and the header value was incorrectly used in my ajax call